# Array Reverse with non duplicate

Tags: c#

I have write this program for "Reversing array and after reversing not showing duplicate elements", but it prints just till second last element:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length / 2; i++)
{
    int tmp = a[i];//Getting First/current element
    a[i] = a[a.Length - i - 1];//Getting last Element and assigning to first/current                
    a[a.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
}

int j=0;
for(int i=0;i< a.Length;i++)
{
    j=i+1;
    if(j < a.Length)
    {
        if (a[i] != a[j])
            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
    }
    j++;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question? If it is you'll probably better figure it out yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, please ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in debug?

Comment: Instead of reversing the array in place, why not just step through it backwards in your duplicate-removing loop?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl OP clearly states the code doesn't work as intended. Questions about non-working code are off-topic on CR.SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is not using LINQ:

```
foreach (int i in a.Reverse().Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However, as you seem to want to do it manually, here's an implementation for that:

```
IEnumerable<T> Reverse<T>(this IList<T> arr)
{
    if (arr == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    for(int i = arr.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) yield return arr[i];
}
IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    Hashset<T> tmpHash = new Hashset<T>();
    foreach (T item in list) tmpHash.Add(item);
    return tmpHash;
}
//your method is now simple as:
a.Reverse().Distinct(); //hey, looks like LINQ but I've implemented it myself.
```

Comment: What, If I have to implement it without LinQ? :)

Comment: Then that's a school assignment and I'm not meant to help you with that.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance simply say you don't know how to use without LINQ, instead of saying I am not meant to help you :\

Comment: @alzaimar Trigger happy, huh? It's always easier to criticize those who create something than putting in the effort oneself, right? And: It does answer the question.

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Here, just to show you that I can do it I'll add it.

Comment: @DennisTraub: No it is not easier and your attempt does not answer the question "What am I doing wrong", but simply provides a different solution. And that is not what the questineer has been asking for.

Comment: @alzaimar After your incessant (useless) complaining, I've added a solution that is more like the OP's.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - you wouldn't get a 3k rep if you couldn't do something primitive, id revert to your original answer..

Comment: @Sayse They're both there.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, I know and my upvote stands, just pointing out you shouldnt need to justify :)

Comment: @DennisTraub: You're right. It should read 'the' instead of 'your' attempt. To late to change, but I guess you will survive.

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
        var arr = new int[] {1,2,4,5,6,4,5};
        var tmp = arr.Reverse().Distinct();
```

hope this help.

Comment: Small note: it's funny how alzaimar didn't complain about this one.

Answer (score 0):

When `i = a.Length-1` `j = a.Length` so `j >= a.Length` so for the last one `i` `Console.WriteLine(a[i]);` isn't called